# Can someone give me a noob guide to get eztz up and running on my ubuntu system? I'm getting the following error

Tags: tezos-client, setup, eztz

eztz.rpc.getBalance("tz1ZzQFmd6e2YTUrkggADWUj5c68wsynpkCZ").then(function(res){
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBalance' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm i eztz` wont work.

Instead you can add eztz's git repo as a dependency in your package.json

```
"dependencies": {   
    "eztz": "git://github.com/TezTech/eztz.git#0c6b93ffdd774f7ed3c528058f854deb0649a61c"  
}
```

After that you just run `npm i` or `yarn` to install the package.

When you want to use the library you have to import it

```
import { eztz } from 'eztz';
```

...or use require.

```
var { eztz } = require('eztz');
```